# ORACLE SQL Developer - see exact results of UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to see exact results of an executed update statement in SQL Developer instead of only number of rows updated? Of course before commiting the statement. I'd like to see what changes were made to rows affected by statement and which rows were affected, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: You can use [`RETURNING`](http://psoug.org/definition/RETURNING.htm)

Comment: And this link from Oracle-base: [DML RETURNING INTO Clause](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause.php)

Comment: Thanks, returning into a table helped me a bit. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think theres a way to get exactly what you want, ie, to see the exact results of an update statement.

Its almost always a good idea to run a select query with the same conditions in your WHERE clause of your update or delete statements to see the records that would be affected before running any non-trivial update or delete statements.

You could also use the SQL History tab (View (in the menu bar) -> SQL History or press F8) to see all the SQL thats been executed in the past. This works on Oracle SQL Developer version 3.1.xx

Comment: Of course, but I have a really complicated correlated update statement, which doesn't give proper results in a SELECT clause. I'll try RETURNING.